# Is there any Widget/Way to show my html file in my mobile app which is developed using GWT,MGWT,GwtPhoneGap

Tags: gwt, cordova, mgwt

I'm beginner to MGWT and GwtPhoneGap.I have .html file which having some hyperlinks and text content and few images. I want to place a button in my view ,when I tapped the button I want to open the my html page on the same view. For this I tried GWT Hyperlink,Frame classes, But not succeeded. Is there any direct widget support given from GwtPhoneGap or else give me the approach to reach my requirement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Frame f = new Frame("yourfile.html")` works for me. Check your url.

Comment: this is fine incase of browser, but it is not working in mobile-iphone and iPad

Comment: I have done this for iPad using mgwt and it works. post your code

Comment: I wrongly given my url path.This is working. thanks a lot user905374

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.widget.LayoutPanel main = new com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.widget.LayoutPanel();

com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Frame frame = new com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Frame(link);
frame.setSize("100%", "100%");

main.add(frame);
```